# angularjs can't assign variable to html5 video src

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I got an error of `Error while interpolating: videos/{{video.name}}` with below code :

```
<div ng-repeat='video in videos'>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <video controls>
          <source src="videos/{{video.name}}" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
        {{video.name}} // this worked
        </div>
    </div>
```

Tried ng-src too but doesn't work. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

Use this filter,

```
app.filter("trustUrl", ['$sce', function ($sce) {
        return function (recordingUrl) {
            return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(recordingUrl);
        };
    }]);
```

**HTML**

```
    <video controls>
      <source src="videos/{{video.name | trustUrl}}" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
```

Comment: video.name is just name like 'tarzen 2016 - something something'

Comment: ok then form the url using javascript and apply the trustUrl for entire url

Comment: [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating: videos/{{video.name}}

Comment: why did you remove the answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

**Html :**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat='video in videos'>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <video controls>
          <source src="videos/{{video.name}}" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
        {{video.name}} // this worked
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.videos = [
      {"name":"alpha"},
      {"name":"beta"},
      {"name":"gama"}
    ]
});
```

## [Working demo!](https://jsfiddle.net/39q1xya6/)

Comment: your 'working demo' is so big, but can the video be played?

Comment: Big means ? .. I dont know the exact streaming url but it will work. Its just a answer of your question and demo how to parse the controller data in view.

Comment: Actually this question is not easy, it's a bug in angularjs https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1352